# Android Java - Iterate through user's gallery

Tags: java, android

I need a way to iterate through all image files user is storing on their device, like a gallery app would.
But I need to load 1 to 20 images at a time & I need it to be sorted from the oldest to the newest.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using recursion and filtering out the files with specific extension , for example you can create a method like this that return a list of all the images with extension .jpg in your phone :

first define a list of a model you have , let say MyImage with properties name and path as global variable :

```
List<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then create this method to iterate through all files on your phone storage and filling our list with image only :

```
private void getMyFiles(File dir) {
        File files[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (files!=null){
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    getMyFiles(file);
                } else {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
                        images.add(new MyImage(file.getName(),file.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call this method as :

```
getMyFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Comment: I used mediastore instead. It's likely faster, and the way Android intended. Thanks tho